# Matrix patterns

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two 9x9 matrices, A and B.

I would like to create a large matrix C with the following pattern

```
 A B B B B B
 B A B B B B
 B B A B B B
 B B B A B B
 B B B B A B
 B B B B B A
```

As you can see, the A matrices are on the diagonal, the B are everywhere else. I'm trying to create a code so that this pattern continues no matter how great the dimensions are.

E.g. 10 matrices x 10 matrices still has matrix A along the diagonal and B's everywhere else.

Best to use horzcat and vertcat or something else like blkdiag? I'd rather not convert these matrices to cells as matrix A and B already contain information.

Thank you everyone for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about (refined)

```
maskcell = repmat( {ones(size(A))}, 1, 10 );
maskdiag = blkdiag( maskcell{:} );
AA = repmat( {A}, 1, 10 );
AD = blkdiag( AA{:} );
BB = repmat( B, 10, 10 );
C = BB .* (maskdiag == 0) + AD
```

Following on from the entirely valid comments below, I added the 'mask' to ensure that the correct pieces are selected from C.

Comment: This will have problems if A contains a `0`.

Comment: I would recommend that you set all the zeros in `A` to `Inf, use Edric's code and set all the `Inf` back to `0` with`isinf`

Comment: @Tetra: Try the code with `A = [1 2 ;3 0];` and `B = [5 5;5 5]`. You'll see that the diagonal blocks aren't `A` but `[1 2;3 5]`.

Comment: Oh I can see! That is problematic indeed. I've managed to make this code work over time but redefining the matrices might be a problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks @Jacob for pointing out the flaw in my approach. Adding the 'mask' should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

C=B(~eye(size(B)))+A(eye(size(A))) should get you what you want. Could be a faster way to combine the use of eye though...

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look! An interesting answer, I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

kron(eye(10), A) + kron(~eye(10), B)